# Problem with osmosis syntax

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I want to create a light version of global map (only with cities and highways and natural objects). How to use osmosis correctly with multiple tags list? For example I try this command with no success:

```
osmosis \
--read-pbf file=1.pbf \
--tf accept-nodes place=* --tf accept-nodes highway=* \
--tf accept-ways place=* --tf accept-ways highway=* \
--tf reject-relations \
--write-xml output.osm
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) ... some people say it is easier to use, and also faster.

Please have a closer look at its parameter definition in the OSM wiki ...

Try your queries first on a small raw OSM data file, to test how to include and exclude OSM elements you need.